# Installing WoW with wine 1.6 on 14.04

Tags: wine

I'm VERY new to ubuntu.  I haven't the slightest clue about how half of this works (it was given to me) The main thing I am interested in is playing WoW.  I've already installed wine 1.6 and the game client for WoW.  I right clicked on the WoW set up to open it with wine.  I got battle net installed and logged in.  However, every time I click install it force closes and comes up with a blizzard error.  The only solutions I could find were ones that you could do if you'd already had wow installed, only i can't even get that far.  I really don't know what to do here, i appreciate any help!

Comment: According to http://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps.html (a good first address to check whether a game is reliably supported in wine) WoW isn't supported.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that. I read on more than one site that wow could indeed run with wine. I'll be installing windows because frankly it's just too complicated for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WoW has Platinum rating in [Wine App DB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28973) meaning it should work perfectly. Just install newer wine as described [here](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

Comment: Ok I'll try that before going to windows.thank you!

Comment: Check Add DB page - it usually has a lot of useful info about installation and fixing issues with the game.

Comment: I re downloaded wine via the link you gave and tried firing it up again and it's working flawlessly! Thanks again techtonik :)